# How to return custom results from Jest Test

Tags: jestjs

I am running jest.RunCLI({},'path');

I have a custom reporter class and all is working well.

I want to add more data to the results. From each test. For example if I want to return specific test failure information that would help in future debugging.

```
    const projectRootPath = path.join(process.cwd(),'myproject');
    const jestConfig = {
        automock: false,
        bail: 0,
        json: false,
        rootDir: '/home/user/myprojects/tests',
        reporters: ['../custom-reporter.cjs']
   };

   jest.runCLI(jestConfig, [projectRootPath])
        .then((result)=>{
            console.log = console_log;
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e);
    });
```

Now supposing I have a test file that contains

```
describe('My tests', ()=>{
    it('Does a test',()=>{
        //How can I return this to the aggregated results?
        let reallyImportant = 'Really must log this somewhere useful, with the results would be good';
    });
});
```

See comment line for the question in context.

So far I have tried monkey patching the jest object. Didn't work.
Tried redirecting console.log. Doesn't work for any console logs inside the test fixture.

Any ideas?